# ngTable doesn't work with UI-Router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ngtable

I always used the directive ngTable with ngRoute module. However, I recently migrated to the UI-Router for better fit the project I'm developing right now.

But for some reason, ngTable does not work correctly with the UI-Router.
The table is generated normally, however the settings do not.
It is not created neither the header nor paging. As the group also is not working.

I also tried to create the table header manually, but I noticed that it disappears when I add the attribute "ng-include" with the value "templates.header".

I'm used the following versions:
ngTable - 1.0.0-beta.9
UI-Router - 0.2.15

Someone have come across this problem? I can not find the solution anywhere.

---

JavaScript:

```
app.controller("users", function($http, $rootScope, $stateParams, $scope, NgTableParams) {
    $scope.users = {};

    $http({
        method: "POST",
        url: "./controllers/users/read.php",
        data: {
            id: $stateParams.id,
            language_id: $rootScope.globals.language.id
        }
    }).success(function(response) {
        $scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams({
            count: 10,
            sorting: {
                name: "asc"
            }
        }, {
            dataset: response
        });

        $scope.users = response;
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<table ng-table="tableParams" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <tr ng-repeat="row in $data">
        <td data-title="'txt.pages.users.fields.name' | translate" sortable="'name'" width="45%">
            {{ row.name }}
        </td>
        <td data-title="'txt.pages.users.fields.email' | translate" sortable="'email'" width="45%">
            {{ row.email }}
        </td>
        <td data-title="'txt.pages.users.fields.actions' | translate" width="10%">
            <button ng-click="edit(row.id)" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">
                <icon class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></icon>
            </button>
            <button ng-click="delete(row)" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
                <icon class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></icon>
            </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

stateProvider:

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state("site", {
        url: "/",
        views: {
            "outside@": {
                templateUrl: "./template/site/index/read.html"
            },
            "inside@site": {
                templateUrl: "./template/site/home/read.html"
            }
        }
    }).state("cms", {
        url: "/cms",
        views: {
            "outside@": {
                templateUrl: "./template/cms/index/read.html"
            }
        }
    }).state("dashboard", {
        parent: "cms",
        url: "/dashboard",
        views: {
            "inside@cms": {
                templateUrl: "./template/cms/dashboard/read.html"
            }
        }
    }).state("login", {
        parent: "cms",
        url: "/login",
        views: {
            "inside@cms": {
                templateUrl: "./template/cms/login/read.html"
            }
        }
    }).state("users", {
        parent: "cms",
        url: "/users",
        views: {
            "inside@cms": {
                controller: "users",
                templateUrl: "./template/cms/users/read.html"
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code samples. It's impossible to answer your question in it's current state.

Comment: Sorry for that. I completely forgot.

Comment: Please post the state definition too. It's important for us to be able to see how that is defined.

Comment: Router used shouldn't have any effect on what gets rendered in each view. Note that `ng-include` creates child scope, try using a custom directive template instead

Comment: During the test, when I updated the page, the pagination appears (without header). But when I updated again, without editing any code, disappeared again.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `$users` instead of `$data` in below line.

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in $data">
```

Comment: $data is the variable used by ngTable.